# What type of wasp is this?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, wasps

I've been trying to match this wasp to photos, but it seems like every species has something that doesn't quite match up. I killed it in my home in Indiana, USA. My best guess is a Northern Paper Wasp (*Polistes fuscatus*). Does that seem right? I read they can sometimes be dark in color like this one.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to tell from the image, but using [this species key for *Polistes* wasps](https://cjai.biologicalsurvey.ca/bmc_05/key_polistes.html), it is reasonable to conclude that your wasp is either *P. metricus* or *P. fuscatus*.

If you look at this image of a *P. metricus* female, you can see the dull reddish markings on the abdomen:

[image]

On your image, you can see the same markings on the abdomen, at a different angle:

[image]

Based on these markings, your wasp is most likely *Polistes metricus*. You can read more about this insect [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polistes_metricus) and [here](https://cjai.biologicalsurvey.ca/bmc_05/78p_metricus.html).

[Here is a link to the image I modified.](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Metricus_Paper_Wasp_(Polistes_metricus)_at_trailhead_-_Flickr_-_Jay_Sturner.jpg#globalusage)